# Error sending an email CakePHP

Tags: email, cakephp

i get "Unknown email configuration 'gmail' " error , while trying to send an email using Cakephp ,is that because i'm sending it from localhost (xampp) ?

```
if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
       $message='Click on the link below to complete registration ';
       $confirmation_link='www.sitename.com/users/verify/t:'.$hash.'/n:'.$this->data['User']['username'].'';
       App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
       $email = new CakeEmail('gmail');
       $email->Email->from = 'myemail@gmail.com';
       $email->Email->to=$this->data['User']['email'];
       $email->Email->subject = 'Confirm Registration';
       $email->Email->smtpOptions = array(
       'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
       'port' => 465,
       'username' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
       'password' => 'mypassword',
       'transport' => 'Smtp'
       );
       $email->send($message . " " . $confirmation_link);
       $this->Session->setFlash(__('you should activate your account'));
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `new CakeEmail('gmail')` you have to config `gmail` in your configure file (/Config/email.php) such as:

```
public $gmail = [
    'transport' => 'Mail',
    'from' => 'you@localhost',
    //'charset' => 'utf-8',
    //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
];
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html

`new CakeEmail('gmail')` will read your `gmail` config and you will not have to configure it in your application.

If you do all your configuration in your application, perhaps you would like to use `new CakeEmail();`

Comment: thanks so much man , No more errors ! but is sending email using localhost with cakephp is possible ? i couldn't find any reference about that

Comment: It really depends on the environment of your localhost. If we configure the environment right, it is possible to send email  with localhost. Just treat it like a real server. When you develop on a real server directly, it is also a 'localhost', am I right?